# Objective-C: trimming whitespace

Tags: objective-c, removing-whitespace

I have to be missing something. I'm trying to trim the data being pulled from an array but my app crashes on the trim method.

```
                //pull values
 NSString* thisXStr = [thisSetArray objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString* thisYStr = [thisSetArray objectAtIndex:1];

 //cleaning up all the white space
 NSString *thisXStrTrim = [thisXStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
 NSString *thisYStrTrim = [thisYStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a copy of the array objects:
NSString *thisXStr = [NSString stringWithString:[thisSetArray objectAtIndex:0]];
...

Answer (score 0):

Crap, never mind, stupid syntax error on a NSLog...